# How to search specific nearby places

Tags: java, android

I am creating a Google Maps app. In my app I am searching for nearby ATMs by using Places type "ATM". It all works perfectly, but I have to find specific nearby ATMs such as Axis bank ATMs. So how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the same in my app . Use the following function for the same:

```
private void showNearbyAtms(){
            Uri mapIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q= Axis atm");
            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mapIntentUri);
            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
            if (getActivity() != null && mapIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(mapIntent);
            }
        }
```